# Find rows where one column value match and other does not

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have two tables A and B

Table A

```
CODE TYPE
A 1
A 2
A 3
B 1
C 1
C 2
```

Table B

```
CODE TYPE
A 1
A 2
A 4
B 2
C 1
C 3
```

I want to return rows where CODE is in both tables but TYPE is not and also CODE has more than one TYPE in both tables so my result would be

```
 CODE TYPE SOURCE
    A 3 Table A
    A 4 Table B
    C 2 Table A
    C 3 Table B
```

Any help with this?

Comment: the result should also have `B 1` and `B 2` as well.

Comment: select * from A
inner join B
on A.CODE = B.CODE
where A.TYPE <> B.TYPE
and A.CODE in (select CODE from A group by code having count(Code) > 1)
and B.CODE in (select CODE from B group by code having count(Code) > 1)

Comment: I don't want B 1 and B 2 in my result

Comment: Is source a required field...?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think this covers both of your conditions.

```
select code, coalesce(typeA, typeB) as type, src
from
    (
    select
        coalesce(a.code, b.code) as code,
        a.type as typeA,
        b.type as typeB,
        case when b.type is null then 'A' when a.type is null then 'B' end as src,
        count(a.code) over (partition by coalesce(a.code, b.code)) as countA,
        count(b.code) over (partition by coalesce(a.code, b.code)) as countB
    from
        A a full outer join B b
            on b.code = a.code and b.type = a.type
    ) T
where
        countA >= 2 and countB >= 2
    and (typeA is null or typeB is null)
```

Comment: alias A & B would not be available in your WHERE Condition on your outer select

Comment: Thanks @shawnt00 the solution you offered works for me

Comment: wouldn't this break down if say the code/type column had duplicate records in TableA because the count is not distinct? such as all of table A records for A where 5 then A 5 A would still show up but it is really only 1 type in Table A?  In his example data this wouldn't be an issue because code to type is unique.

Comment: @Matt Yeah, I'm sure that would mess it up.

Answer (score 2):

You can use a `full join` to see if the code matches and check if the type is `null` on either of the tables.

```
select coalesce(a.code,b.code) code, coalesce(a.type,b.type) type,
case when b.type is null then 'A' when a.type is null then 'B' end src
from a
full join b on a.code = b.code and a.type = b.type
where a.type is null or b.type is null
```

To limit the results to codes which have more than one type, use

```
select x.code, coalesce(a.type,b.type) type,
case when b.type is null then 'Table A' when a.type is null then 'Table B' end src
from a
full join b on a.code = b.code and a.type = b.type
join (select a.code from a join b on a.code = b.code 
      group by a.code having count(*) > 1) x on x.code = a.code or x.code = b.code
where a.type is null or b.type is null
order by 1
```

Comment: Thanks for solution @vkp.

Answer (score 0):

Using union

```
with tu as (
    select CODE, TYPE, src='Table A'
    from TableA
    union all
    select CODE, TYPE, src='Table B'
    from TableB
)
select CODE, TYPE, max(src)
from tu t1
where exists (select 1 from tu t2 where t2.CODE=t1.CODE and t2.src=t1.src and t1.TYPE <> t2.TYPE)
group by CODE, TYPE
having count(*)=1
order by CODE, TYPE
```